# Using an IAM Role, a script works in AWS cli, but not in AWS Tools for powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-iam, aws-cli

This is a very strange issue I have no idea how to answer.

So we have a script which lists the security group associated with the box - written in powershell:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

if ($boxName -eq $NULL)
{
    Write-Host "Box name wasn't specified!"
    Exit 1    
}

if ($region -eq $NULL)
{
   $region = "eu-west-1"
}

Set-DefaultAWSRegion -Region $region

$searchFor =@(
    @{
        name = 'tag:Name'
        values = $boxName
    }
)
$SecurityGrp = Get-EC2SecurityGroup -Filter $searchFor

Write-Host $SecurityGrp.GroupName

function DisplayIPPermissions {
    param (
        $Permission
    )

    Write-Host "`nSecurity Group Name $($Permission.GroupName)"
    Write-Host "Security Group ID $($Permission.GroupId)"
    Write-Host "Protocol $($Permission.IpProtocol)"
    Write-Host "FromPort: $($Permission.FromPort)"
    Write-Host "ToPort: $($Permission.ToPort)"

    Write-Host "IPv4 Ranges";
    foreach($iprange in $Permission.Ipv4Ranges)
    {
        Write-Host $iprange.CidrIp
    }

    Write-Host "UserGroupIdPairs"

    foreach($pair in $Permission.UserGroupIdPairs)
    {
        Write-Host $pair.GroupId
    }
}


Write-Host "`n`nInBound`n`n"

foreach($rule in $SecurityGrp.IPPermissions)
{
    DisplayIPPermissions $rule
}

Write-Host "`n`nOutBound`n`n"
foreach($rule in $SecurityGrp.IPPermissionsEgress)
{
    DisplayIPPermissions $rule
}
```

This works perfectly when using IAM access keys running on my local machine. It returns the details of the security group including the name, id, ports and usergroup pairs.

However, when I run this on an instance EC2 with an IAM Role attached I get some very strange behaviour. The script runs with no errors, but it has empty string for all the values EXCEPT the ports. Example output:

```
InBound



Security Group Name 
Security Group ID 
Protocol tcp
FromPort: 3579
ToPort: 3579
IPv4 Ranges
UserGroupIdPairs

Security Group Name 
Security Group ID 
Protocol tcp
FromPort: 22
ToPort: 22
IPv4 Ranges
UserGroupIdPairs

Security Group Name 
Security Group ID 
Protocol tcp
FromPort: 443
ToPort: 443
IPv4 Ranges
UserGroupIdPairs


OutBound



Security Group Name 
Security Group ID 
Protocol tcp
FromPort: 3579
ToPort: 3579
IPv4 Ranges
UserGroupIdPairs

Security Group Name 
Security Group ID 
Protocol -1
FromPort: 0
ToPort: 0
IPv4 Ranges
UserGroupIdPairs

Security Group Name 
Security Group ID 
Protocol tcp
FromPort: 443
ToPort: 443
IPv4 Ranges
UserGroupIdPairs
```

This is completely baffling as for some reason the code is clearly iterating through the rules and is correctly getting the ports. I can't understand why the ports are treated differently.

Stranger still this command:
`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$boxName"`

works perfectly using the IAM Role.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by updating the AWS Tools